# How to draw horizontal line in blackberry

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

I tried following code for draw a single line horizontal line but it is not working. i am not getting what is the problem.

```java
HorizontalFieldManager horline = new HorizontalFieldManager()
{
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
    {
        super.paint(graphics);
        graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
        graphics.drawLine(5, 21,10, 20);                      
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```java
HorizontalFieldManager horline = new HorizontalFieldManager()
{
   protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
   {
      super.paint(graphics);
      graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
   }
};
horline.add(new SeparatorField(SeparatorField.LINE_HORIZONTAL|SeparatorField.VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS));
```

Comment: hi thanks for u r help. why my line color is not going to be change ?

Answer (score 2):

There's at least a couple problems here:

### Extent

The *extent* of a field (or manager) is basically the size of that field on screen.  This size is normally set by a `Field` object in its `layout()` method, or by a `Manager` object in its `sublayout()` method.  The problem is that your `HorizontalFieldManager` does not override these methods to set the size (by calling `setExtent()`), and it doesn't look like you add any fields to the manager.  So, I believe your `horline` manager object simply has a size of {0, 0}.  Drawing outside its extent doesn't do anything.

### Manager vs Field

Manager classes are containers for fields.  In this case, all you have is a line.  I would definitely not use a Manager (including HorizontalFieldManager) for this, since you're not putting any fields into it, and there is overhead to adding Manager objects.  Use a lighter-weight Field, or maybe even modify the `paint()` or `paintBackground()` method on whatever class *contains* this code ... you don't show us that, so I can't say for sure.

If you want to represent the line with a `Field`, then this will work:

```java
  Field line = new Field() {
     protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        setExtent(20, 21);            
     }
     protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        int oldColor = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(5, 21,10, 20);          
        g.setColor(oldColor);
     }         
  };
  add(line);
```

Note that I am setting the extent to width=20, height=21, because those are the maximum coordinates you pass to `drawLine()`.  Also, because your y values are 20 and 21, this isn't actually a truly horizontal line.

### add()

This might have simply been left out of the code you *show* to keep the question short, but whether you use a Manager or a Field, you do need to remember to call `add()` for your field/manager object.  Objects created, but not added to a screen, will never show.  In your case, the `setExtent()` problem would *also* have caused this problem.

---

### Update:

As Dinesh shows in his answer, you could *also* solve the problem by using `SeparatorField`.  However, I believe that only gives you purely horizontal/vertical lines.  Because of the coordinates in your code, I wasn't sure if you needed the ability to draw lines of any orientation ... if you do, then overriding `paint()` is necessary.  If not, use `SeparatorField` ... but hopefully, you learned something from this answer, too :).

Comment: I believe you can draw vertical lines with SepartorField - look at the SeparatorField style settings.

Comment: @PeterStrange, Looking at the field constants, it looks like it.  Of course, the description in the class documentation specifically says "horizontal" ... but I'm sure this isn't the first javadoc to be incorrect :).  I'm drawing a blank trying to remember the geometrical term for a line that's *either* horizontal or vertical ... anyway, it doesn't do diagonal, which is what the question showed (although, very possibly a typo).